# Dimension of convex arrangements for hypergraphs

Tags: discrete-geometry, reference-request, graph-theory, convex-geometry

Suppose you have a hypergraph H on n vertices. Let d be the smallest integer such that we can find an arrangement A of convex subsets in R<sup>d</sup> so that H represent the intersections of sets in A.

1. Has this notion been formalized and studied? If yes, what is it called?
2. What is known about upper- or, more importantly for me, lower bounds on d in terms of some (any) characteristics of H.

I'll be grateful for any relevant reference.

(For ordinary graphs, it is known that $d\leq 3$, so the interesting analogue would rather be the *boxicity* of a graph introduced by Roberts (1968).  Various upper bounds on the boxicity are known, but lower bounds are rarer -- one appears in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3175) by Adiga, Chandran and  Sivadasan.)